# Python Byte-encoding functions do not work as expected

Tags: python, byte, endianness, pwntools, binascii

I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal number,
like the stack address `0x7ffd6fa90940`,
into its corresponding Byte representation `b'\x40\x09\xa9\x6f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00'`.
Just like how it is represented in gdb:

```
pwndbg> hexdump $rsp \32
+#### 0x7fffffffdc##   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  │                 │
+0000 0x7fffffffdc30  e0 af 4b 00 15 00 00 00 [40 dc ff ff ff 7f 00 00] │..K.....│........│
+0010 0x7fffffffdc40  25 39 24 73 00 00 00 00 [50 dc ff ff ff 7f 00 00] │%9$s....│P.......│
```

I found three functions, but they do not convert the hex number as expected:

```py
import pwnlib.util.packing
import binascii

addr = '0000' + '0x7ffd6fa90940'[2:]
addr = binascii.unhexlify(addr)
print("[DEBUG] addr: {}".format(addr))
# Prints big endian: b'\x00\x00\x7f\xfdo\xa9\t@'
#                !=  b'\x7f\xfd\x6f\xa9\x09\x40'

addr = 0x7ffd6fa90940
addr = pwnlib.util.packing.p64(addr, endian='little')
print("[DEBUG] addr: {}".format(addr))
# Prints lit endian: b'@\t\xa9o\xfd\x7f\x00\x00'
#                !=  b'\x7f\xfd\x6f\xa9\x09\x40'

addr = 0x7ffd6fa90940
addr = pwnlib.util.packing.pack(addr, word_size=64, endianness='little')
print("[DEBUG] addr: {}".format(addr))
# Prints lit endian: b'@\t\xa9o\xfd\x7f\x00\x00'
#                !=  b'\x7f\xfd\x6f\xa9\x09\x40'

# Custom implementation:
addr = '0000' + '0x7ffd6fa90940'[2:]
addr = ''.join(reversed(['\\x'+addr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(addr), 2)]))
print("[DEBUG] addr: {}".format(addr))
# Prints lit endian notation as a string: \x40\x09\xa9\x6f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00
# But how to convert to actual Bytes?:  b'\x40\x09\xa9\x6f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00'
#
addr = addr.encode('utf-8').replace(b'\\\\',b'\\')
print("[DEBUG] addr: {}".format(addr))
# Results in:   b'\\x40\\x09\\xa9\\x6f\\xfd\\x7f\\x00\\x00'
```

Why is that and how can it be converted as expected?
Thanks in advance for any hints, links, and answers!

Comment: Your second and third tries already work. If a byte value can be shown as printable ASCII character, it is represented as such instead of the `\x00` representation but it is the same value.

Comment: The `struct` module was created just for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the following:

```py
import struct
struct.pack( "@P", 0x7ffd6fa90940 )   # Or just `"P"`
```

That said, your second and third solutions give what you want.

```
>>> b'\x40\x09\xa9\x6f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00' == b'@\t\xa9o\xfd\x7f\x00\x00'
True
```

They are equivalent because

- `b'\x40'` and `b'@'` both produce byte 0x40.
- `b'\x6f'` and `b'o'` both produce byte 0x6F.
- `b'\x09'` and `b'\t'` both produce byte 0x09.